# Converting string field into date field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, convert, fields-attributes, date

In QGIS I have a layer with points which represent the fatal road accidents and the field `"dates_14_D"` contains their date but its type is string. I would like to convert this string field to date field but the OK button is inactive. What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: What does it say when you click on "more info"?

Comment: I think that the date format is wrong; QGIS expects something like 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: Parse Error:                                                                                                Eval Error: The conversion  " % 1 " was not possible.

Comment: I converted the format like @ArMoraer said an I repeated the procedure but again the OK button is inactive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm surprised I haven't seen this before. Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious :)

Although you're using a different locale to me, you're using the same date format as I do in the UK, `dd/MM/yyyy`. I get a slightly different error (on QGIS 2.16.1) but it doesn't like that date format.

You can get around this by creating a short python script in the function editor tab of the expression editor.

- Go into the function editor tab in the expression editor
- Create a new function (<kbd>New file</kbd> button)
- paste the following into the code window. You may get indentation errors, so manually re-indent with spaces if needed
- click on <kbd>Load</kbd> button to save the changes
- switch back to the expression tab
- look under the python heading, should now see a function called **parse_date_dmy**

---

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QDate

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Python')
def parse_date_dmy(fromval, feature, parent):
    return QDate.fromString(fromval, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

If you use QGIS 3.# and get an error about PyQt4, then instead use PyQt5, i.e. replace line 3 with

```py
...
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate
...
```

You can then enter an expression like so, using your field name :

```py
parse_date_dmy("mydate")
```

If all is well, you should see something like this...

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It worked. But, for some dates, the outcome was null. Is there any explanation?

Comment: try **d/M/yyyy** as your format string (see [Qt date format string spec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1), although note that this is a Qt5 page). I tested it on days and months with single and double figures and it seemed to work OK. If that works I'll update my answer.

Comment: The first time I run this procedure, the format of the date was d/M/yyyy. I have tried to run this with the format  d/M/yyyy again and the outcome of some records was null as it above mentioned. In addition, I run this with the format dd/MM/yyyy and the outcome was that all the records were null. Have I done sth wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know what it was like back in 2016, but as of QGIS 3.10, this is implemented in in the available functions in QGIS in the expression editor or the Field calculator. The documentation on the right (in the field calc dialog) gives you the solution of:

```py
to_date("MyDateFieldNameWithDatesAsStrings" , 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

and hit <kbd>Ok</kbd>. Adapt the "format" to the one present in your attribute table. For example, if your dates look something like `07.3.03`, the correct format for that would be `dd.M.yy`*. Pay attention to capitalization, as the symbol `m` stands for "minutes" and `M` stands for "months".

This is not a format anybody should use. If you get a file with that format, please talk to the sender's superior. This will not stand!

Comment: I should add, that even though you pass `'dd/MM/yyyy'` as a parameter, QGIS will output the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format (as that's what it understands as 'date' format)

Answer (score 2):

> **An update for QGIS 3 of the crystal clear answer by @Steven Kay**

You can get around this by creating a short Python script in the function editor tab of the expression editor.

- Go into the function editor tab in the expression editor
- Create a new function (<kbd>New file</kbd> button)
- paste the following into the code window. You may get indentation errors, so manually re-indent with spaces if needed
- click on <kbd>Load</kbd> button to save the changes
- switch back to the expression tab
- look under the python heading, should now see a function called **parse_date_dmy**

---

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Python')
def parse_date_dmy(fromval, feature, parent):
    return QDate.fromString(fromval, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

You can then enter an expression like so, using your field name :-

```py
parse_date_dmy("mydate")
```

If all is well, you should see something like this...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use :

```
to_date( regexp_substr( "MAJ" , '/(\\d+$)' ) || '-' || regexp_substr( "MAJ" , '/(\\d+)/' ) || '-' || regexp_substr( "MAJ" , '^(\\d+)/' ) )
```

With MAJ as your date field (dd/MM/YYYY).

Answer (score 0):

Workaround-----you are unable to edit this (your error message above) until you save into a GeoPackage, per [Why can't I edit attribute table imported through 'text as layer'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76396/why-cant-i-edit-attribute-table-imported-through-text-as-layer)