# qgis convert string to date

Tags: qgis, python

I'm having the same problem from this
[previous question.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212274/how-to-convert-a-string-field-to-a-date-field)

I keep getting some nulls after running expression. Not sure why it works on some dates

I have dates(strings) in the form 1/4/2005, 11/11/2004, etc

Here is code I used in field calculator:

btw data will be uploaded to django app using PostGeSQL

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QDate

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Python')
def parse_date_dmy(fromval, feature, parent):
    return QDate.fromString(fromval, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: fast guess is, that there is a difference between 1/4/2005 and 01/04/2005

Comment: can you say which datas work and which don't?

Comment: the text i'm trying to convert is month/day/year like 1/29/2014.  could i have the wrong format?  I'm using dd/MM/yyyy in expression

Comment: just noticed some years are yy only, not yyyy