# Removing the time zone from datetime field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, datetime, qgsexpression, time-zone

How can I get rid of the time zone in the date/time field?

So I have a GeoPackage with the following data:

[image]

and want to get just 2021-06-07 16:25:40

Comment: Which field type is this?

Comment: @Erik it is date/time field

Comment: Are you sure? Because using 3.16 I can't find an option to add the timezone to the datetime.

Comment: @Erik yes, I'm sure. Got this value from string using parsing function (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212274/converting-string-field-into-date-field-in-qgis): "QDateTime.fromString(fromval, 'dd.MM.yyyy h:mm:ss')". The timezone was unwanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my QGIS (3.22), when I use `datetime` format, I get timezone information included by default. You can convert it to a string to get rid of it - use this expression, where `datetime` is the name of the field containing the datetime-information:

```
left(to_string(datetime), 19)
```

However, you can't use the resulting string field as a `datetime` field any more. Including timezone makes sense - as `2021-12-06 14:48:41` is not the same everywhere on Earth.

Comment: thank you! so there is an issue with the version?

Comment: No, I think including timezone is intended, that's not an issue. This format is not primarily intended for visualization - if you want to visualize, best convert to a string.

Answer (score 3):

After inspecting provided GeoPackage I could not find the problem in any of your datetime fields, specifically `"Save_times1"` and `"Loc1"`.

[image: fields]

[image: attribute_table]

---

Proceed with `RMC > Properties > Attributes Forms > Fields` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html#ls-forms)) where change the Field Format from `ISO Date Time` into `Date Time`.

[image: window]

*Before:*
[image: attribute_table1]

*After:*
[image: attribute_table2]

Comment: it's already date time, I've checked. I will share my data in a second.

Comment: @Taras: I downloaded the Geopacke provided by kartographinya and indeed, I get the same format, including timezone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4lOM.png This, however, is a visualization issue and I guess it has to do with system settings - QGIS just takes the options used by the operation system. As you see in my screenshot, if you try to edit a field, the timezone disappers.

Comment: So the question is why the timezone bothers you? In case you use several timezones, it matters, of course. If that is the case, I think you should reformulate the question or ask a new one.  If you just want to use the time as a text somewhere, without the disturbing timeone text, converting the field to a string as proposed in my answer should work.

Comment: @Taras which version of QGIS do you use?

Comment: QGIS 3.18. and you?

Comment: @Taras 3.22. Ok, it seems that it is just a visualization of a system.

Comment: Yeap. I do think so

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the `field calculator`. Then tick `update existing field`. Select your desired field and type:

`regexp_replace( "date" , '(MSK)', '')`

Then hit `OK`. Good Luck.

Comment: thank you, but doesn't work.

Comment: You should replace "date" WITH YOUR FIELD NAME e.g. "date_field"! Then try again.

Comment: Yes, I've done that

Comment: try `regexp_replace( "date" , '\\s(MSK)', ''). It must have worked. I've got confused right now.